# Apache POI Pivot Table: Distinct count (Excel 2013)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I have to create a pivottable in Excel 2013 with Apache POI including a value field using the "distinct count" summarize function (e.g. as explained in http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/distinct-count-in-pivot-tables-finally-in-excel-2013/)

AFAIK it is not included in poi's DataConsolidateFunction. Does someone know a workaround for this?

I am currently using POI Version 3.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, POI uses the Excel 2010 specification right now, so the appropriate nodes may not exist in the API. You can check by renaming a sample that has the functionality you are looking for, then look in the spec at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm to see if the appropriate XML nodes are supported in the file format. POI uses the first edition spec. There has been talk of supporting something newer, but it has not yet been done.

Comment: I tried to solve it somehow with POI and messing around with the xml-files, but I didn't succeed. In the end I solved the problem with a xslm-Template and a VBA-macro.